# How to incorporate an if condition to creat non-continuous function in R?

Tags: r

We are asked to write a function in using function **outer** to calculate a double summation function.

Initially, I have my code written in the following form and it works:

```
funC<-function(n){
  express<-function(r,s){
    s^2/(10+4*r^3)
  }
  s<-1:n
  r<-1:n
  g<-outer(r,s,"express")
  g[row(g)< col(g)]<-0
  sum(g)
}
```

However, I noticed that this function will run super slow when I increase my input n to a large number, say 10000.

I think this is because in my programme many calculations are redundant that I should get rid of.

So I tried to create a different **express** function such that this will assign 0 to the output if r>s.

```
funC<-function(n){
  express<-function(r,s){
    if(r<=s){s^2/(10+4*r^3)}
          else {0}}
  s<-1:n
  r<-1:n
  g<-outer(r,s,"express")

  sum(g)
  g
}
```

However, it turns out that this code doesn't work. Here's the warning message I received.

> Warning message: In if (r <= s) { :   the condition has length > 1 and
>   only the first element will be used

I searched on the internet but cannot find any information regarding creating a segmented function... could someone please give me some hints? I am sorry if I made mistakes in my code... I am new to this programme...

Comment: The warning message is because of the length of the logical vector which return >1. I guess you need `ifelse`

Answer (score 0):

```
funC<-function(n){
  express<-function(r,s){
    ifelse(r>=s,s^2/(10+4*r^3),0)}
  s<-1:n
  r<-1:n
  g<-outer(r,s,"express")

  sum(g)
  g
}
```

You think `outer` is a element-wise function both for **r** and **s**, which means every time `outer` select 1 element from **r** and 1 element from **s** to propose calculation.

However, from your warning information, I think `outer` uses vector **r** and each element of **s** to calculate result each time.In this situation, using `ifelse(testvector,yes,no)` can get your result. Checkout with `?ifelse`

Each time `outer` function tries to calculate a row of your result matrix **g**. Thus, it will generate a logical vector. Put the logical vector in `ifelse()` as the first parameter and then set the parameters of **yes**(when logic equals to TRUE) and **no**. You will get what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I tried this code as well but it seems the output is not correct in this case...

Comment: in `ifelse()`, you can try with **r >= s**. The result will consistent with your raw function. It's a matter about calculating upper triangular or lower triangular. The mistake is hidden in your code and I didn't examine this details before I posted. Both of us should be carefully. ：）